# Есть собранный HTML и CSS файлы и надо их соединить и заставить их работать

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть несколько HTML файлов, в которых уже написаны стили. Их надо как-то соединить вместе но есть проблема. При открытии этих файлов там вот такая картина:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А строк там на пару десятков тыс.

Comment: Файлы взяты у фейсбука?) Попробуйте раскодировать base64 строку)

Comment: Это иконка, закодированная в base64. Не обращайте особого внимания и соединяйте всё остальное.

Answer (score 0):

Эти строки закодированы в base64, если есть возможность раскодируйте их каким либо декодером, например:
https://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: Это больше комментарий, чем полноценный ответ